# Add checkbox to tab in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox, tabbar

How could you add a checkbox to a tab in a tabnavigator or a tabbar in Flex?  Or would you have to create your own tabbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to roll out your own.

Start [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part3_as_components_1.html).